# WPF datagrid usercontrol binding

Tags: c#, wpf

Is it possible to add the same usercontrol to datagrid column1 and column2?
There is only one usercontrol.

```
<DataGrid SelectionUnit="Cell" Name="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="test1" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="test2" Binding="{Binding image1}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="test3" Binding="{Binding image2}"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="column1">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <local:UcFrameLessSheetInfoListviewItem />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="column2">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:Name="test">
                        <local:UcFrameLessSheetInfoListviewItem />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yDuB.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To share the cell template, you have to declare it as a resource, in the grid, the user control or at the App level :

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TestCellTemplate" DataType="viewModel:MyItemsType">
        <local:UcFrameLessSheetInfoListviewItem />
    </DataTemplate>
...
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Then you can reference it using `StaticResource`:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="column1" CellTemplate="{StaticResource TestCellTemplate}" />
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="column2" CellTemplate="{StaticResource TestCellTemplate}" />
```

Comment: hi Orace. Thank you for your comment.
 I tried it, but same image in column1 and column2.
uploaded my source code. please Can you check it?
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mv_1KFFKZrpTi5h7_vOE9NTfCzS99GnA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: For me, you ask for the same user control and now you complain because they are the same. I'm sorry I don't understand your needs.